# How to select and print only the value of a nested array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm trying to create an array only from the `basename` of the url's of `$member1` and `$member2` and so on to `$member(n)`.

the base array i'm using looks like this for a reason, since I'm using it for another `foreach` loop.

So the scheme looks like this:

```
$member1 = 'http://www.bla-bla.com/aFolder/anotherFolder';
$member2 = 'http://www.yada-yada.com/yetAnotherFolder/innerFolder';
$member3 = 'http://www.boo-boo.com/abcs/folder';

//this is the main array
$teams = array(
    array("url" => $member1, "selector" => "a"),
    array("url" => $member2, "selector" => "input"),
    array("url" => $member3, "selector" => "h1"),...,...);
```

I would like to build a foreach that would create at the end an array with the values with `basename($member(n))`.

I would like my result to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => anotherFolder
    [1] => innerFolder
    [2] => folder
)
```

Thus far I've tried different ways to extract that specific value with no avail, I couldn't find a way on how to extract that specific value.
I'll appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$basenames = [];
foreach ($teams as $team) {
    $basenames[] = basename($team['url']);
}
```

Comment: Actually that solved it, I have another issue that has to do with replacing empty array values with a string such as 'empty', would you be able to edit your answer if I insert/ edit my question, or should I open a new question?

Comment: Sounds like a new question :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function getBaseName($array){
    $return=array();
    foreach($array as $arr)
    {
        $exp=explode("/",$arr['url']);
        $return[]=array_pop($exp);
    }
    return $return;
}

$basenames[]=getBaseName($teams);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, try this:

```
$resArray = array();

foreach($teams as $team){
    $resArray[] = basename($team['url']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `array_map` and `basename` functions:

```
...
$result = array_map(function($v){ return basename($v['url']); }, $teams);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array();

foreach($teams as $team){
        $array[] = basename($team["url"]);
}
print_r($array);
```

will print

```
Array
(
    [0] => anotherFolder
    [1] => innerFolder
    [2] => folder
)
```